# Set focus to a particular column on empty query grid

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

The ACCESS form opens a simple query in `acReadOnly` mode. Using a button on the form, I would like to set the focus to a specific column in the query grid. The code works correctly if the query returns at least one record.
If the query returns 0 records, the `dataSheet.Controls("Field2").SetFocus` statement returns error 2105 - "You can't go to the specified record".
Is there a way to set the Focus to a particular column in the empty query grid?

```vb
'main module
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub start()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmtest"
End Sub
```

```vb
'frmTest module
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim dataSheet As Object

Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryTest1", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
    'qryTest1: select field1,field2,field3 from myTable
    
    Set dataSheet = Screen.ActiveDatasheet
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSetFocus_Click()
    dataSheet.SetFocus
    MsgBox dataSheet.SelTop
    dataSheet.Controls("Field2").SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: How can this work when datasheet object is not set? Why open query and not a form?

Comment: in short no as in acReadOnly the form's recordsetType should be set to SnapShot and in Access when the recordsetType is SnapShot and there are no records, then the Bound Controls in the details section of the form don't exist.  So an error happens when you try to set the focus of a control that doesn't exist.  There are not enough details provided to be specific about what you should do.  Certainly you can test for no records with something like:if( DCount("SomeID", "qryTest1")=0) then .... EndIF.  Then if you really must you could add a record to qryTest1. set focus to it...